# Embed PDF file doesnt work

Tags: php, pdf, embed

So I want to embed decoded pdf file in my view, but it doesnt work.

I am using following code

```
<embed src="localhost/tmp/invoices/1481634077_tmp_pdf.pdf" width="100%" height="700" type='application/pdf'>
```

This code doesnt work, but if I call file name directly from browser I can see file, also if I want to embed file from external page it is working

example

```
<embed src="http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf" width="100%" height="700" type='application/pdf'>
```

I have also tried to upload my App online and I have same problems (link from my domain doesnt show up PDF-s but from other I can read it.

Also I have tried same with Iframe and Object tag

Thank you for helping

Comment: Because you are missing protocol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a relative URL.

So, if the URL of your page is `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost/index.php`, the URL you're using in the `src` attribute (`localhost/tmp/invoices/1481634077_tmp_pdf.pdf`) will actually refer to `http://localhost/localhost/tmp/invoices/1481634077_tmp_pdf.pdf`

Which is probably not what you want.

You can either:

- Use an absolute URL: `http://localhost/tmp/invoices/1481634077_tmp_pdf.pdf`
  (starting with `http://`)
  However, you will have to change it if you upload your site to a domain other than localhost.
- Use the correct relative URL: `tmp/invoices/1481634077_tmp_pdf.pdf`
- Use a root-relative URL: `/tmp/invoices/1481634077_tmp_pdf.pdf`
  (starting with a `/`)